# NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError after call function by user

Tags: angular

I´m making a translation sytem in my angular library.

**my.component.html**

```
...
<mat-form-field *ngIf="langSelected">
    <mat-label>{{ 'LANG_NAME' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="langSelected" [compareWith]="objectComparisonFunction">
        <mat-select-trigger>
            <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{langSelected.countryCode.toLowerCase()}}"></i> {{langSelected.name}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option (click)="applylang(allowedLang.key)" *ngFor="let allowedLang of translateUI.allowedLanguages" [value]="allowedLang">
           <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{allowedLang.countryCode.toLowerCase()}}"></i>
                  {{ allowedLang.name }}
        </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
...
```

An error appears when the user changes the language using `applylang(allowedLang.key)`

> Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'

I understood I´m trying to change value after ngAfterViewChecked() but I did not find the solution to fix this.

**my.component.ts**

```
...
constructor( public currentUser: UserService, private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef ){
   this.user = null;
}
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    super.ngAfterViewInit();
    if ( isNotNullOrUndefined( this.user ) ) {
       this.currentUser.setUser( this.user );
    }
 }
 ...
 applylang( language: string ) {
    const data = this.currentUser.data.getValue();
    console.error('-- PING');
    if ( isNotNullOrUndefined( data ) ) {
      data.preferences.lang = language;
      this.currentUser.setUser( data ); // <-- this cause the error
      this.cdref.detectChanges(); // That changes anything
    }
    /*this.translateUI.refreshTranslate();
    this.displayPreferences();*/
  }
...
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {UserItem} from '../models/user/user-item.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  data: BehaviorSubject<UserItem> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  setUser( userData: UserItem) {
    const tmpUserItem = new UserItem( userData.displayName, userData.preferences );
    this.data.next(tmpUserItem);
  }
}
```

I tried various things I found from several Web posts without success.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: What is the full error text in the browser debugger console? Cause it looks like there is a boolean variable in your code is been used in the template which has changed after angular change detection has been triggered. You will need to check where was this error thrown to adjust your logic or force detecting changes at this assignment time.

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure if this is a correct answer but the error disappears :

**my.component.ts**

```
@Component({
 ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: In this case you are just disabling the default change detection on any change. Which tells angular to check for changes only when an @Input or async pipe has changed. In this case the error won't be thrown.

Comment: It is recommended to use OnPush strategy but you should be aware that the dom will not always be automatically updated on variable changes that happen in the component typescript. Your should then call detectChanges on ChangeDetectorRef to update the dom.